# Bind variable to list

Tags: c#, list, class, properties

I have a really simple hierarchy : 1 interface inherited by a few classes, looking similar to this but missing a few properties :

```
public interface Test
{
    List<double> Numbers { get; set; }
    double Result { get; set; }
}

public class A : Test
{
    public List<double> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<double>();
    public double Result { get; set; }
}

public class B : Test
{
    public List<double> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<double>();
    public double Result { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a sample code of what I'm trying to achieve :

```
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();
        a.Numbers.Add(b.Result);
        Console.WriteLine(a.Numbers.Last());
        b.Result = 50;
        Console.WriteLine(a.Numbers.Last());
```

**Output**

> 0
>
> 0

The problem is that at line 5 I'm changing the value of `b.Result` but i want to reflect this change in the `a.Numbers` list which contains the previous state of `b.Result`, how can I do this ?

Comment: `public List<DoubleByRef> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<DoubleByRef>();` I am curious what this line does. At my side it does not compile due to this line.

Comment: @vivek it does compile in C# 6. This is a new feature called **Property Initialization**. Check out the features of C# 6 :  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: @user3185569 Thanks, I was unware about this. Will work on c#6.0 soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`double` is a `value type`, whenever you pass it around, you create a copy of it. It is not passed by reference, so when you say `a.Numbers.Add(b.Result);` you're actually creating a copy of `b.Result` and passing to the `Add` method.

You can read this [Article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/parameters.html) to understand this concept with examples.

**From C# specifications:**

> ⦁ Types and variables
>
> There are two kinds of types in C#: value types
>   and reference types. Variables of value types directly contain their
>   data whereas variables of reference types store references to their
>   data, the latter being known as objects. With reference types, it is
>   possible for two variables to reference the same object and thus
>   possible for operations on one variable to affect the object
>   referenced by the other variable. With value types, the variables each
>   have their own copy of the data, and it is not possible for operations
>   on one to affect the other (except in the case of ref and out
>   parameter variables).

Here is a **workaround**, it is not recommended anyway:

```
public interface Test
{
    List<DoubleByRef> Numbers { get; set; }
    DoubleByRef Result { get; set; }
}

public class A : Test
{
    public List<DoubleByRef> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<DoubleByRef>();
    public DoubleByRef Result { get; set; } = new DoubleByRef(0);
}

public class B : Test
{
    public List<DoubleByRef> Numbers { get; set; } = new List<DoubleByRef>();
    public DoubleByRef Result { get; set; } = new DoubleByRef(0);
}

public class DoubleByRef
{
    public double Value { set; get; }
    public DoubleByRef(double d)
    {
        Value = d;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.Numbers.Add(b.Result);
Console.WriteLine(a.Numbers.Last());
b.Result.Value = 50;
Console.WriteLine(a.Numbers.Last());
```

Prints:

```
0
50
```